# Powershell copy/paste various multiple rows

Tags: excel, powershell

I want to copy multiple rows from the excel source sheet (journal) to destination sheet (Data) from column A to F starting at row 11.  Each Journal sheet can have a various number of rows containing data from 2 rows to 2000 rows.  Need to copy all rows with data until the first empty row or find the word 'Subtotal' in column A which also signifies the last row. Then paste into Data sheet at A2:F2.

```
Param(
   $path = “D:\Input\Jnl.xlsx”,
   $worksheet1 = “journal”,
   $range1 = “(A11,F11$(($Source.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows|Select -Last 1).Row)"),
   $worksheet2 = "Data",
   $range2 = “A2:F2"
   ) #end param
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$Excel.visible = $false
$Workbook = $excel.Workbooks.open($path)
$Worksheet = $Workbook.WorkSheets.item($worksheet1)
$worksheet.activate() 
$range = $WorkSheet.Range($range1)
$range.Copy() | out-null
$Worksheet = $Workbook.Worksheets.item($worksheet2)
$Range = $Worksheet.Range($range2)
$Range.PasteSpecial(-4163)
$Workbook.SaveAs("D:\Complete\Datafinal.xlsx")
$Excel.Quit()
```

The $range works fine if the range is fixed but with variable numbers of rows from one sheet to the next it's not usable.

Comment: Have you considered using the [Import-Excel](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel) module? It will be a lot easier to do what you want.

Comment: Hey @Santiago Squarzon, sounds interesting but as a new comer to PS I'm not sure how to use the Import-Excel module in my situation. I'll check out your link. Thanks

Comment: So, you have multiple worksheets on input file and want to export all data to a destination file but you didn't specify how. Should it be to different worksheets on destination or all data concatenated? In addition, would be very useful to have an example of how does a sheet of the input file looks like in CSV format.

Comment: The variable `$source` is not defined anywhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I would get rid of the `param` block, as it isn't necessary for how the
  code is written and just complicates things
- Use `UsedRange.Rows.Count` and add 10 (for the
  starting point offset) to get the last row for the *copy range*
- Use the row count from earlier and add 1 to get the last row for the
  *paste range*
- Notice that the two workbooks (source and destination) are **opened**,
  and the appropriate worksheets **activated**. Your code was only doing
  this with the first one.

```
    $excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    
    $src = "path-to-src-file"
    $workbook1 = $excel.Workbooks.Open($src)
    $wsName1 = "worksheet1-name"
    $worksheet1 = $workbook1.Worksheets.Item($wsName1)
    $worksheet1.Activate()
    $rowCount = $worksheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    $lastRow1 = ($rowCount + 10)
    $range1 = $worksheet1.Range("A11:F$lastRow1")
    $range1.Copy() | Out-Null
    
    $dst = "path-to-dst-file"
    $workbook2 = $excel.Workbooks.Open($dst)
    $wsName2 = "worksheet2-name"
    $worksheet2 = $workbook2.Worksheets.Item($wsName2)
    $worksheet2.Activate()
    $lastRow2 = ($rowCount + 1)
    $range2 = $worksheet2.Range("A2:F$lastRow2")
    $range2.PasteSpecial(-4163)
    $workbook2.SaveAs($dst)
    
    $excel.Quit()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @D-squared. This worked for me.  Would it be possible to stop the copy on the line containing the word 'Subtotal' in column A. In a majority of the files I'm processing this is the case but not all.

Comment: Try removing the row with `$lastRow1 = ($rowCount + 10)` and replacing it with the following three lines: `$colA = $worksheet1.Range("A1").EntireColumn`; `$subtotalRow = $colA.Find("subtotal").Row`; `$lastRow1 = ($subtotalRow - 1)`

Comment: Thanks again @D-squared. Worked first time! 